# Adding method in an existing interface which has different implementations in large number of classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism

If we have an interface which is being implemented by large number of classes in our application, and we need to add a method to the interface, What is the recommended way to do it?

Would the approach differ if we are using older version of java (let's say 1.5) vs if we are using newer version of java (let's say 1.8).

Comment: Will a single common implementation of the new method be valid for all classes? Or will different classes need their own implementations?

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a popular answer, but it seems right to me that the operation you envisage is a difficult one.

Interfaces define a service contract between different sub-systems. Changing that contract *should* be more difficult that changing an implementation. Java 8 introduced "default" methods on interfaces, which converts the interface from being a strict contract, to a kind of abstract base class. I guess it might take some of the sting out of changing interfaces, but I think it's right that developers should feel that sting.

In fact, in an ideal world, all interfaces would be agreed in advance, and there should never be a need to change one. I guess that's impractical, but I see no need to make it easy.

The short answer, I think, is that if you change an interface, you should reflect on what changes are needed in all the implemented classes, grit your teeth, and get on and make them.

Comment: "*converts the interface from being a strict contract, to a kind of abstract base class*" This is incorrect. It's not an abstract class in any sense. If it were, you would not be able to implement 2 of them. They can't contain state. It converts the interface from a strict contract to *a more permissive contract*, that's all.

Comment: It surely is the correct answer, be it popular or not.

Comment: @Michael The wording was "a kind of abstract base class", not "an abstract base class". And I agree with Kevin's view. Interfaces are closer to abstract base classes now with a bit of multiple inheritance added into the game.

Comment: Normally when I implement an abstract base class in C++, I want to provide some, but not all, functionality in the abstract base class. Concrete classes that extend the abstract base class fill in the missing, specified functionality. Despite what @Michael says, this is _precisely_ what you can do with interfaces since Java 8. The un-Java-like language doesn't change the principle.

Comment: @Michael And you're confusing pragmatic programming with nit-picking uses of terminology

Comment: The term "kind of" is _inherently_ imprecise in everyday speech, and deliberately so. Even when discussing object-oriented programming, it doesn't mean "subclass of" ;)

Comment: If I paint an orange green, does it "convert it" from an orange to a kind of apple? It's more similar in 1 dimension, colour.

Comment: That's a straw man. We aren't talking about fruit. There isn't a taxonomy of "things to do with computer programming" that you can fit every concept into a precise position within. That you object to my terminology doesn't stop my argument being valid.

Comment: Abstract classes and interfaces are well-defined. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1

Comment: Let's just agree to differ.

Answer (score 1):

you should always follow the principle of `"Open for extension Close for modification"`
if u add a new method the repercussions will be in all the Classes implementing it , U have to implement the method to all (be it java 5 or 8 until its a default method), so better

```
Create a new interface and the needful classes should extend it
```

Answer (score 0):

> we **need** to add a method to the interface

Well then there's no way around it. Without any context for what you're adding and why, I'll take your word for it that you do *need to*. Make sure that's actually the case.

**Java 5:** add the method. Fix all the classes implementing it.

You can consider adding a default to a new abstract base class which implements the interface, and make all implementations extend that. Then if you're in the same situation in the future you'll have an easier time.

**Java 8:** add a default method